# Express and Mongoose Issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get Mongoose to return me a collection, it works fine on the Mongo Client from the Command line, example:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.16
>   
>   connecting to: test
>   
>   db.users;
>   
>   test.users
>   
>   db.collection.find();
>   
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5986483ddfdfdcbb0d23eb01"), "id" : 1, "firstName" : "Andrew", "lastName" : "Greg", "email" : "agreg@gmail.com" }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("59864993dfdfdcbb0d23eb02"), "id" : 2, "firstName" : "Greg", "lastName" : "Smith", "email" : "gsmith@protonmail.com" }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("598649d5dfdfdcbb0d23eb03"), "id" : 3, "firstName" : "Kim", "lastName" : "T", "email" : "random@outlook.com" }

My Current express code is:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import {graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress} from 'graphql-server-express';
import {makeExecutableSchema} from 'graphql-tools';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
//import MongoClient from 'mongodb';
//import mysql from 'mysql';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Mongo Connection Error:'));
db.on('open', function(err, doc){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    var userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', userSchema,'users');
    userModel.find().then(function(err,doc){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        console.log(doc);
    });
});
```

Returns nothing :S, I've tried this on two different servers and I get the same result.  I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 (on the remote server I tested), I've turned off AppArmor and I've made sure to setup the bindIp on 127.0.0.1, port 127.0.0.1.

I've checked everything I can think or, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Looking at your shell commands the collection name is actually called `"collection"`. So your model would need that as the third argument, i.e `model('userModel', userSchema, 'collection')`. The additional line  `db.users;` that you typed and it's "response" `test.users` does identify that there is a collection called that name, but the one you are actually showing the data from is called `"collection"`. Because that is what you are asking by `db.collection.find()`. You can look with `db.users.find()`, but it probably contains no documents due to a similar error on your part.

Comment: You also have quite a few concepts wrong and I would suggest re-reading the documentation guides, since they are quite explicit in examples. If indeed this is an "imported data source" as it would appear to be, then I would also strongly suggest actually using the `id` field as the value of `_id` or where possible removing it altogether. `_id` is a "Primary Key", which was the role of your `id` in the mysql source. So it's not a good idea to have "two" primary keys, and there is a good reason why `ObjectId` is the default instead of an integer.

Comment: Thanks :), This is just a test, the data is meaningless right now.

Comment: Thank you!!! That was the problem